# Credit card validation with not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, validation

I am using jQuery Credit Card Validation Plugin: **Smart Validate** to validate credit cards.

It is working fine, when downloaded it and implemented in my localhost.

But when I tried to implement the same in wordpress it is not working and when I checked the console I am getting:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).ccvalidate is not a function
jQuery('.cc-container').ccvalidate({ onvalidate: function(isValid) {
```

Why its not working with wordpress? How can I resolve the issue?

In the fiddle you can see the normal working and there it is working fine.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwhqy/1/)

Comment: You can warp the code using this function `(function(){
   // your stuff here
})(); //<----this invokes the function immediately.`

Comment: @Maidul I didn't get your point. How can I correct it ?

Comment: `(function(){    // your stuff here jQuery('.cc-container').ccvalidate({ onvalidate: function(isValid) {} })();`

Comment: @Maidul Its already wrapped. Please check the fiddle. There you can see the code.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham How you are embeding the scripts? Putting scripts directly to the `header/footer` templates **OR** by enqueuing?

Comment: @RahilWazir I have put the scripts in the content area. In the file page.php

Comment: @LeoTAbraham Don't hide it from us. Show us the contents of page.php here.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has jquery has `jQuery.noConflict();` enabled, this means that the use of the `$()` shorthand doesn't work by default. You could try wrapping the entire code in `()(jQuery);` (or just change all the `$()`'s to `jQuery()`). See [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) for more information.